# Cucumber and Devise, Too many Redirects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, devise

I am trying to create a test with cucumber for Devise. This is my feature

```
Feature: Login to locomotive
  In order to login to locomotive
  As a user 
  I want to be able to use Locomotive

Scenario: Login to locomotive
    Given I am a authenticated user
    Then I should see "logged in as <email>"
    Then show me the page
```

and this is my user steps

```
Given /^I am not authenticated$/ do
  visit('/users/sign_out') # ensure that at least
end

Given /^I have one\s+user "([^\"]*)" with password "([^\"]*)" and username "([^\"]*)"$/ do |email, password, username|
  @user = User.new(:email => email,
           :username => username,
           :first_name => 'Josh',
           :last_name => 'Crowder',
           :password => password,
           :password_confirmation => password).save!
end

Given /^I am a authenticated user$/ do
  email = 'testing@man.net'
  username = 'josh'
  password = 'secretpass'

  Given %{I have one user "#{email}" with password "#{password}" and username "#{username}"}
  And %{I go to login}
  And %{I fill in "user_login" with "#{email}"}
  And %{I fill in "user_password" with "#{password}"}
  And %{I press "Sign in"}
end
```

Im getting this error message

```
F--

(::) failed steps (::)

redirected more than 5 times, check for infinite redirects. (Capybara::InfiniteRedirectError)
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>'
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:14:in `with_scope'
./features/step_definitions/web_steps.rb:28:in `/^(?:|I )press "([^"]*)"(?: within "([^"]*)")?$/'
features/user_authentication.feature:7:in `Given I am a authenticated user'

Failing Scenarios:
cucumber features/user_authentication.feature:6 # Scenario: Login to locomotive

1 scenario (1 failed)
3 steps (1 failed, 2 skipped)
```

I have no clue why this is happening, any ideas?

Comment: Please include your controller code for the login post action as well as any relevant before and after filters.

Comment: Could you post your routes too, please? Have you specified a root?

Answer (score 0):

Could be tons of things -- no way to tell without more code. Some possibilities:

- are you requiring authentication for the login page? That can get you in a loop. You want to exclude the "open" pages (like sign_in) from your authentication solution
- you could put the Then Show Me The page higher so you can see *exactly* what's happening
- you could reset back to the defaults of your authentication solution (eg devise) by commenting out other routes just to see what's going on

What happens when you try it through the browser?

Comment: I had the problem that in ran in the browser but not in the tests, too. I ended up looking into `log/test.log` where I could see where the redirects got. This helped me find the root cause of the problem. (It was triggered by some stuff present in my dev db but not in the test db)